# How can I search a keyword in Hibernate Search with definite article?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search DSL to make the query and I need to search some keyword in French.

For example, when I use this query:

```
Query query = queryBuilder.keyword().onField("normVal").matching("asthme").createQuery();
```

It just matches the word asthme on field "normVal", but I want the query can find the word "l'asthme" or "d'asthme" too.

Is someone know how can I do this in Hibernate Search?????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `matching` method with wildcard characters in your string: `?` represents a single character and `*` represents any character sequence

So your code, for example, could be:

```
 Query query = queryBuilder.keyword().onField("normVal").matching("*asthme*").createQuery();
```

You can find more details [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html)

**Edit after OP comment**

If you have fixed values to search, like words with articles, you can also try something like this instead of wildcars:

```
Query query = queryBuilder.bool()
.should(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("normVal").matching("l'asthme").createQuery())
.should(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("normVal").matching("d'asthme").createQuery())
.should(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("normVal").matching("asthme").createQuery())
.createQuery();
```

Please notice that the `should` method will work like an `OR` query operator

Comment: I have tried this method, but search with wildcard will increase the time of searching and I saw it is recommended that the query does not start with either ? or *. Is there some other way to solve this?

Comment: If you already tried this so what's the real question? That's not what you asked for, next time be more specific please.

Comment: I'm sorry that I just wanna find a solution which can solve this problem and dont reduce the performance of the system.

Comment: But in really searching, the l' or d' is not fixed, perhaps there will be some other caracters. I need a dynamic way. Moreover, if I use "??asthme", does it means it will find the "l'asthme" and "d'asthme"?

Comment: Yes it should work but it will have the same performance as the starting '*' character, indeed it is usually recommended that the query does not start with either ? or *, as you pointed up in your first comment